# How can I run the application written in Golang as a Windows service

Tags: c++, c, go, winapi, service

I cannot use the screenshot application that I developed with the Win32 api as a Windows Background service.
I install and run it as a Windows background service, I have no problem so far.
My problem: The service doesn't give me a printout. Doesn't take a screenshot.
I tried making another simple app. I tried sending a message using the [OutputDebugStringW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringw)  function but my problem was not resolved.

- Can't develop Windows Background application with Win32 api?
- Why am I having this problem?
- How can I run my screenshot application as windows background service using win32 api?

My Windows background service that is not producing output

```
    package main
    
    import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "time"
    
        "github.com/checkgo/win"
        "github.com/kardianos/service"
    )
    
    var logger service.Logger
    
    type program struct {
        exit chan struct{}
    }
    
    func (p *program) Start(s service.Service) error {
        if service.Interactive() {
            logger.Info("Running in terminal.")
        } else {
            logger.Info("Running under service manager.")
        }
        p.exit = make(chan struct{})
    
        // Start should not block. Do the actual work async.
        go p.run()
        return nil
    }
    func (p *program) run() {
        logger.Infof("I'm running %v.", service.Platform())
        ticker := time.NewTicker(2 * time.Second)
        for {
            select {
            case tm := <-ticker.C:
                win.OutputDebugString(fmt.Sprintf("%s : %v", "This is test message", tm))
            case <-p.exit:
                ticker.Stop()
            }
        } // link to whaterver image from the web
    
    }
    func (p *program) Stop(s service.Service) error {
        // Stop should not block. Return with a few seconds.
        return nil
    }
    
    func main() {
        svcConfig := &service.Config{
            Name:        "GoServiceExampleSimple",
            DisplayName: "Go Service Example",
            Description: "This is an example Go service.",
        }
    
        prg := &program{}
        s, err := service.New(prg, svcConfig)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        logger, err = s.Logger(nil)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        err = s.Run()
        if err != nil {
            logger.Error(err)
        }
    }
```

ScreenShot:
[DebugView and Windows Services Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuWjy.png)

Comment: IIRC, Windows services run under a different desktop instance and so cannot take user screenshots.

Comment: @MartinJames is correct, services run isolated in session 0 on a seperate WindowStation and Desktop. See https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation/ba-p/372361

Comment: I understood what you mean by your answers. If someone has an idea for a solution, I would appreciate it if you could share it.

Comment: If your goal is to take a screenshot from a user's session you should spawn a process from your service in the user's session (fetch token with `wtsqueryusertoken` and then call `CreateProcessAsUser`)

Comment: Have you developed your application and compiled it on another Windows system?
Windows does not allow any "unknown" application to run. Windows considers it a harmful file. He simply ignores him.
Try: Right-click on the executable file and give it access to run.

Comment: Please don't add answers to your questions. I have rolled back/edited your question. Please write a new answer instead.

Comment: Thanks @Yatin I thought it would be wrong to answer my own question.

Comment: @RecaiCingöz no no it completely fine and in fact encouraged. If you want, you can also accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If a service is running in the security context of the LocalSystem
> account but does not include the SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS
> attribute, it uses the following window station and desktop:
> Service-0x0-3e7$\default. This window station is not interactive, so
> the service cannot display a user interface. In addition, processes
> created by the service cannot display a user interface.

Refer: [Window Station and Desktop Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winstation/window-station-and-desktop-creation)

> The interactive window station is the only window station that can
> display a user interface or receive user input. It is assigned to the
> logon session of the interactive user, and contains the keyboard,
> mouse, and display device. It is always named "WinSta0". All other
> window stations are noninteractive, which means they cannot display a
> user interface or receive user input.

Refer: [Window Stations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winstation/window-stations)

It is said that screen you want to capture is in the default desktop of the interactive window station (Winsta0\default). You can create a child process in `Winsta0\default`, and the child process is used for screenshots. Use [CreateProcessAsUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasusera) to call the child process in the service.

Refer to the following C++ code. Although this is not a Go language, I think it is enough to be familiar with the call of winapi.

```
DWORD WINAPI ServiceWorkerThread(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    OutputDebugString(_T("My Sample Service: ServiceWorkerThread: Entry"));
    WCHAR station[] = L"Winsta0\\default";
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;
    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
     
    STARTUPINFO si;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    si.lpDesktop = station;
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    HANDLE hToken;
    bool err = WTSQueryUserToken(WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId(), &hToken);
    WCHAR path[] = L"D:\\child.exe";  //child.exe is used to take screenshots
    if (CreateProcessAsUser(hToken, path, NULL, 0, 0, true, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, 0, 0, &si, &pi))
    {
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Strive Sun - MSFT, I came across this solution suggestion but I haven't had the opportunity to try it yet. I will give information after I test.  I know you from the comments, after proposing a solution, you patiently await your return. :)))

Comment: @RecaiCingöz If you have any question, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks again @Strive Sun - MSFT. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Solved with [CreateProcessAsUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasusera) function.

GOO source codes that I used to solve problems.

**Source code of the Windows background service application:**

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "reflect"
    "sync"
    "syscall"

    "github.com/checkgo/win"
    "github.com/kardianos/service"
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

var logger service.Logger

type program struct {
    exit chan struct{}
}

func (p *program) Start(s service.Service) error {
    if service.Interactive() {
        logger.Info("Running in terminal.")
    } else {
        logger.Info("Running under service manager.")
    }
    p.exit = make(chan struct{})

    // Start should not block. Do the actual work async.
    go p.run()
    return nil
}
func (p *program) run() {
    var wgT sync.WaitGroup
    wgT.Add(1)
    test(&wgT)
    wgT.Wait()
}

func test(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    var saAttr win.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    saAttr.NLength = uint32(reflect.TypeOf(syscall.SecurityAttributes{}).Size())
    saAttr.BInheritHandle = win.TRUE
    saAttr.LpSecurityDescriptor = uintptr(0)

    var si syscall.StartupInfo
    si.Cb = uint32(reflect.TypeOf(syscall.SecurityAttributes{}).Size())
    si.Desktop = windows.StringToUTF16Ptr("Winsta0\\default")
    si.Flags = windows.STARTF_USESTDHANDLES
    var hToken windows.Token
    id := win.WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()
    err := windows.WTSQueryUserToken(uint32(id), &hToken)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Info(err)
    }
    path := windows.StringToUTF16Ptr("C:\\Users\\cingo\\go\\src\\srv\\agent\\test_agent.exe")

    var pi syscall.ProcessInformation
    syscall.CreateProcessAsUser(syscall.Token(hToken),
        path,
        nil,
        nil,
        nil,
        true,
        windows.CREATE_NO_WINDOW,
        nil,
        nil,
        &si,
        &pi)

}

func (p *program) Stop(s service.Service) error {
    // Stop should not block. Return with a few seconds.
    return nil
}

func main() {
    svcConfig := &service.Config{
        Name:        "GoServiceExampleSimple",
        DisplayName: "Go Service Example",
        Description: "This is an example Go service.",
    }

    prg := &program{}
    s, err := service.New(prg, svcConfig)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    logger, err = s.Logger(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = s.Run()
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error(err)
    }
}
```

**Running application**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/checkgo/win"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
        win.OutputDebugString(fmt.Sprintf("%s", "This is test message"))
    }
}
```